# Mmap and struct in C

Tags: c, struct, mmap

I would like to read and write structs with mmap in C.
I have a function named insert_med which allows the insertion of a new struct *med* into the mmap and each struct (with a unique *key*) has to be written in a different position of the array (when a new struct is added, it has to be added in the last empty position of the array).
Two structs *med* CAN'T have the same *key* as you can see in the code bellow. The *key* is unique.
My code isn't working - error messages with the variable "struct map": when declared and when the file is ready to be mmapped - but I don't know why. I think I'm probably doing something the wrong way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define FILEPATH "/tmp/mmapped.bin"
#define NUMINTS (1000)
#define FILESIZE (NUMINTS * sizeof(int))

struct med{
    int key;
    char name[25];
    int quant_min;
    int quant;
};

insert_med(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i;
    int fd;
    int result;
    struct map*;  /* mmapped array of structs */

    /* Open a file for writing.
    *  - Creating the file if it doesn't exist.
    *  - Truncating it to 0 size if it already exists. (not really needed)
    *     
    * Note: "O_WRONLY" mode is not sufficient when mmaping.
    */
    fd = open(FILEPATH, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0600);
    if (fd == -1) {
    perror("Error opening file for writing");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Stretch the file size to the size of the (mmapped) array of structs
     */
    result = lseek(fd, FILESIZE-1, SEEK_SET);
    if (result == -1) {
    close(fd);
    perror("Error calling lseek() to 'stretch' the file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Something needs to be written at the end of the file to
     * have the file actually have the new size.
     * Just writing an empty string at the current file position will do.
     *
     * Note:
     *  - The current position in the file is at the end of the stretched 
     *    file due to the call to lseek().
     *  - An empty string is actually a single '\0' character, so a zero-byte
     *    will be written at the last byte of the file.
     */
    result = write(fd,"",1);
    if (result != 1) {
    close(fd);
    perror("Error writing last byte of the file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Now the file is ready to be mmapped.
     */
    map = (struct*)mmap(0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
    close(fd);
    perror("Error mmapping the file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct med m;
    struct med s;
    int a=0;

    printf("Key of med: ");
    scanf("%d",&m.key);

    //strcmp return "0" when the two strings are equal
    for (i = 0; i <=NUMINTS; ++i) {

    int a=0;
    map[i]=&s;

    read(fd,&s,1);

    if ((strcmp(&m.key,&s.key))==0){
        a++;    
        printf("Med %d already exits. \n",s.key);    
        break;
    }
    }

    if (a==0){
    printf("Name of med: ");
    scanf("%s",&m.name);
    printf("Quant. min. of med: ");
    scanf("%d",&m.quant_min);
    printf("Quant. of med: ");
    scanf("%d",&m.quant);

    map[i]=&m;

    write(fd,&m,1);
    printf("Med %d saved. \n",m.key);
    }

    /* Don't forget to free the mmapped memory
     */
    if (munmap(map, FILESIZE) == -1) {
    perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
    /* Decide here whether to close(fd) and exit() or not. Depends... */
    }

    /* Un-mmaping doesn't close the file, so we still need to do that.
     */
    close(fd);
}
```

Comment: And *isn't working* means?... Error message? Crash?

Comment: error messages with the variable "struct map": when declared and when file is ready to be mmapped

Comment: Compiler message or runtime message?  What exactly is the message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your code, you have:

```
int result;
struct map*;  /* mmapped array of structs */
```

You previously defined `struct med` (and not `struct map`), and you tried to define a variable of type `struct map *` but gave it no name.  The compiler is right to complain.  You probably need something like:

```
int result;
struct med *map = 0;  /* mmapped array of struct med */
```

---

[Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4403667/julia) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697228/mmap-and-struct-in-c/27697316#comment43808020_27697316):

> I now have the following errors:
>
> - `invalid use of undefined type "struct med"`
> - `deferencing pointer to incomplete type`
>
> in `map[i]=&s` and `map[i]=&m`.

Well, I didn't look much further than the first error, but where's there's one, there are usually many.

For example:

```
map = (struct*)mmap(0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

needs the cast changed to `(struct med *)`.

```
map[i]=&s;
```

is wrong. Semantically, `map[i] = s;` would be correct (copy the data from `s` into the mapped array) — but, on second thoughts, the assignment is simply wrong.  Don't do it; delete that line.

Your `FILESIZE` should probably be a multiple of `sizeof(struct map)` rather than a multiple of `sizeof(int)`.

The `read()` on `fd` is dubious at best — remove it; the whole point of `mmap()` is to avoid direct file I/O.

The key values are integers; you don't use `strcmp()` to compare them, and you simply use:

```
if (m.key == map[i].key)
```

The assignment `map[i]=&m;` is wrong, again, and should be deleted, and the `write()` is wrong.  You have an array, `map`, and you access it like you would any other array, and the system handles the I/O behind the scenes.  Note that you should always check that `read()` and `write()` operations worked, but that becomes moot when you delete those operations anyway.

You will need to review how values are assigned to the `map` array, and ensure you don't try to read from uninitialized values in the `map` array.

There may still be other problems; I've not compiled, much less run, the code.  But these comments should help you on your way.

Note that the error messages from the compiler should be helping too; you need to learn how to interpret them.  Make sure you're compiling with enough warnings and that you're fixing all the warnings.  If you use GCC, then `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c11` is a fairly good start (I usually add a bunch of warnings about prototypes and function definitions too — some, but not all, of which are included in the above). Remember, the C compiler knows a lot more about C than you do at this stage of your career; listen to its warnings with care, because you should assume it is correct and you've made a mistake.  That's what I do, and I've been coding in C for more than 30 years now.

---

#### Working code `mm7.c`

The created program is `mm7` (memory map 7; there's no significance to 7 other than it is prime, small and makes the name unique).

A fair amount of the code is left as written in the question, rather than rewrite from scratch.  Note that the code is careful to validate input — it detects and bails out on EOF, rather than blithely continuing and doing nothing useful, for example.  It includes an output loop to print the stored data.  It uses functions to manage parts of the input.  It would be better if all the input were handled in functions.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FILEPATH "/tmp/mmapped.bin"
#define NUMINTS (1000)
#define FILESIZE (NUMINTS * sizeof(struct med))

struct med
{
    int key;
    char name[25];
    int quant_min;
    int quant;
};

static void print_med(const char *tag, const struct med *med)
{
    printf("%s: %4d: Q(%2d, min %2d): %s\n",
           tag, med->key, med->quant, med->quant_min, med->name);
}

static int med_in_map(const struct med *map, int num_meds, int key)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_meds; ++i)
    {
        if (key == map[i].key)
        {
            printf("Med %d already exists.\n", key);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

static int get_new_key(const struct med *map, int num_meds, int *key)
{
    while (printf("Key of med: ") > 0 && scanf("%d", key) == 1)
    {
        if (med_in_map(map, num_meds, *key) == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return EOF;
}

int main(void)
{
    int fd;
    int result;
    struct med *map;  /* mmapped array of structs */

    /* Open a file for writing.
     *  - Creating the file if it doesn't exist.
     *  - Truncating it to 0 size if it already exists. (not really needed)
     *
     * Note: "O_WRONLY" mode is not sufficient when mmapping.
     */
    fd = open(FILEPATH, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0600);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Error opening file for writing");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* NB: ftruncate(fd, FILESIZE); is simpler */
    /* Stretch the file size to the size of the (mmapped) array of structs */
    result = lseek(fd, FILESIZE - 1, SEEK_SET);
    if (result == -1)
    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error calling lseek() to 'stretch' the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Something needs to be written at the end of the file to
     * have the file actually have the new size.
     * Just writing an empty string at the current file position will do.
     *
     * Note:
     *  - The current position in the file is at the end of the stretched
     *    file due to the call to lseek().
     *  - An empty string is actually a single '\0' character, so a zero-byte
     *    will be written at the last byte of the file.
     */
    result = write(fd, "", 1);
    if (result != 1)
    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error writing last byte of the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Now the file is ready to be mmapped.  */
    map = (struct med *)mmap(0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error mmapping the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Input loop */
    int num_meds;
    for (num_meds = 0; num_meds < NUMINTS; num_meds++)
    {
        struct med m;
        memset(&m, '\0', sizeof(m));

        if (get_new_key(map, num_meds, &m.key) == EOF)
            break;

        printf("Name of med: ");
        if (scanf("%s", m.name) != 1)
            break;
        printf("Quant. min. of med: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &m.quant_min) != 1)
            break;
        printf("Quant. of med: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &m.quant) != 1)
            break;

        map[num_meds] = m;

        printf("Med %d saved.\n", m.key);
    }

    /* Output loop */
    printf("\nRecorded meds:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_meds; i++)
    {
        char buffer[32];
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "M%.4d", i);
        print_med(buffer, &map[i]);
    }

    /* Don't forget to free the mmapped memory */
    if (munmap(map, FILESIZE) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
        /* Decide here whether to close(fd) and exit() or not. Depends... */
    }

    /* Un-mmapping doesn't close the file, so we still need to do that.  */
    close(fd);

    /* Remove file? */
    /* unlink(FILEPATH); */
}
```

#### Example data input file `mm7.data`

This simulates terminal input with attempted repeats of the number.

```
1 Hydrocontin 3 5
1
2 Paxodontin 1 1
2
37 Ibuprofen 2 12
129 Butoxydione 12 29
4 Placebo 2 22
37
129
4
2
1
9231 Aspirin 99 99
```

#### Example run with the data file:

```
$ ./mm7 < mm7.data
Key of med: Name of med: Quant. min. of med: Quant. of med: Med 1 saved.
Key of med: Med 1 already exists.
Key of med: Name of med: Quant. min. of med: Quant. of med: Med 2 saved.
Key of med: Med 2 already exists.
Key of med: Name of med: Quant. min. of med: Quant. of med: Med 37 saved.
Key of med: Name of med: Quant. min. of med: Quant. of med: Med 129 saved.
Key of med: Name of med: Quant. min. of med: Quant. of med: Med 4 saved.
Key of med: Med 37 already exists.
Key of med: Med 129 already exists.
Key of med: Med 4 already exists.
Key of med: Med 2 already exists.
Key of med: Med 1 already exists.
Key of med: Name of med: Quant. min. of med: Quant. of med: Med 9231 saved.
Key of med: 
Recorded meds:
M0000:    1: Q( 5, min  3): Hydrocontin
M0001:    2: Q( 1, min  1): Paxodontin
M0002:   37: Q(12, min  2): Ibuprofen
M0003:  129: Q(29, min 12): Butoxydione
M0004:    4: Q(22, min  2): Placebo
M0005: 9231: Q(99, min 99): Aspirin
$
```

The prompts are all on one line for each actual medication because the input was read from a file, not from the keyboard.

#### Hex dump of data file `/tmp/mmapped.bin`

```
$ odx /tmp/mmapped.bin
0x0000: 01 00 00 00 48 79 64 72 6F 63 6F 6E 74 69 6E 00   ....Hydrocontin.
0x0010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0x0020: 03 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 50 61 78 6F   ............Paxo
0x0030: 64 6F 6E 74 69 6E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   dontin..........
0x0040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00   ................
0x0050: 25 00 00 00 49 62 75 70 72 6F 66 65 6E 00 00 00   %...Ibuprofen...
0x0060: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0x0070: 02 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 81 00 00 00 42 75 74 6F   ............Buto
0x0080: 78 79 64 69 6F 6E 65 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   xydione.........
0x0090: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 1D 00 00 00   ................
0x00A0: 04 00 00 00 50 6C 61 63 65 62 6F 00 00 00 00 00   ....Placebo.....
0x00B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0x00C0: 02 00 00 00 16 00 00 00 0F 24 00 00 41 73 70 69   .........$..Aspi
0x00D0: 72 69 6E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   rin.............
0x00E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 63 00 00 00 63 00 00 00   ........c...c...
0x00F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
* (2484)
0x9C40:
$
```

The `memset()` was added because the hex-dump showed garbage in the data structure — harmless garbage, but garbage nonetheless:

```
0x0000: 01 00 00 00 48 79 64 72 6F 63 6F 6E 74 69 6E 00   ....Hydrocontin.
0x0010: 2F 62 69 6E 3A 2F 75 73 72 2F 67 6E 75 2F 62 69   /bin:/usr/gnu/bi
0x0020: 03 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 50 61 78 6F   ............Paxo
0x0030: 64 6F 6E 74 69 6E 00 00 2F 62 69 6E 3A 2F 75 73   dontin../bin:/us
0x0040: 72 2F 67 6E 75 2F 62 69 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00   r/gnu/bi........
…
```

Initializing the structure with:

```
struct med m = { .key = 0, .name = "", .quant = 0, .quant_min = 0 };
```

didn't completely eliminate the garbage because of the padding bytes in the structure after the name (which surprised me!):

```
0x0000: 01 00 00 00 48 79 64 72 6F 63 6F 6E 74 69 6E 00   ....Hydrocontin.
0x0010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2F 62 69   ............./bi
0x0020: 03 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 50 61 78 6F   ............Paxo
0x0030: 64 6F 6E 74 69 6E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   dontin..........
0x0040: 00 00 00 00 00 2F 62 69 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00   ...../bi........
…
```

---

#### Working with a non-empty file

The code no longer includes `O_TRUNC` when creating the file, but that makes the hard-coded file name less appropriate (but I've not fixed that).  The `find_num_entries()` function simply does a linear search through the data to find where the list left off last time.  More sophisticated code would do a binary search through the data to find where the empty entries start.  There's also linear search in the lookup for keys.  It would be better to keep the file in sorted order so that a binary search can be used for that, too.  Indeed, it might be sensible to have a header record in a production version which had a magic number to identify the file type (if the file doesn't start with the correct magic number, it clearly isn't a file that this program wrote, so its contents shouldn't be interpreted), and to record other details such as number of entries and maybe minimum and maximum key values.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FILEPATH "/tmp/mmapped.bin"
#define NUM_MEDS (1000)
#define FILESIZE (NUM_MEDS * sizeof(struct med))

struct med
{
    int key;
    char name[25];
    int quant_min;
    int quant;
};

static void print_med(const char *tag, const struct med *med)
{
    printf("%s: %4d: Q(%2d, min %2d): %s\n",
           tag, med->key, med->quant, med->quant_min, med->name);
}

static int med_in_map(const struct med *map, int num_meds, int key)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_meds; ++i)
    {
        if (key == map[i].key)
        {
            printf("Med %d already exists.\n", key);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

static int get_new_key(const struct med *map, int num_meds, int *key)
{
    while (printf("Key of med: ") > 0 && scanf("%d", key) == 1)
    {
        if (med_in_map(map, num_meds, *key) == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return EOF;
}

static int find_num_entries(const struct med *map, int max_meds)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < max_meds; i++)
    {
        if (map[i].key == 0)
            break;
    }
    return i;
}

int main(void)
{
    int fd;
    int result;
    struct med *map;

    fd = open(FILEPATH, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, (mode_t)0600);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Error opening file for writing");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = ftruncate(fd, FILESIZE);
    if (result == -1)
    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error calling ftruncate() to 'set' the file size");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    map = (struct med *)mmap(0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error mmapping the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Input loop */
    int num_meds;
    for (num_meds = find_num_entries(map, NUM_MEDS); num_meds < NUM_MEDS; num_meds++)
    {
        struct med m;
        memset(&m, '\0', sizeof(m));

        if (get_new_key(map, num_meds, &m.key) == EOF)
            break;

        printf("Name of med: ");
        if (scanf("%s", m.name) != 1)
            break;
        printf("Quant. min. of med: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &m.quant_min) != 1)
            break;
        printf("Quant. of med: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &m.quant) != 1)
            break;

        map[num_meds] = m;

        printf("Med %d saved.\n", m.key);
    }

    /* Output loop */
    printf("\nRecorded meds:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_meds; i++)
    {
        char buffer[32];
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "M%.4d", i);
        print_med(buffer, &map[i]);
    }

    /* Don't forget to free the mmapped memory */
    if (munmap(map, FILESIZE) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
        /* Decide here whether to close(fd) and exit() or not. Depends... */
    }

    /* Un-mmapping doesn't close the file, so we still need to do that.  */
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

You can also make the error reporting simpler using functions analogous to `err_syserr()`, which you can find in answers of mine such as [Creating a file with given size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714834/c-creating-a-file-with-given-size/27725619#27725619).

Comment: Oh yes, it makes sense! I already changed that. Thank you. But I have now the following errors: "invalid use of undefined type "struct med"" and "deferencing pointer to incomplete type" in map[i]=&s and map[i]=&m

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. No more errors. I made those changes! But the struct doens't seem to be written in the file with the line "write(fd,&m,1)". How can the current position of the array map take the values of struct med m?

Comment: You just write `map[i] = m;` — yes, really that simple!

Comment: Thank you! But how do you save the data in a file (meds.dat for example)? For the application to be persistent.

Comment: The `mmap()` function does that.  It maps the file into memory, and any changes you make in memory end up being mapped into the file on disk.  The `munmap()` and `close()` functions finish the job — particularly `munmap()`.  I ran the code I showed to get the result I showed.  There are ways to fettle `mmap()` so that the changes made by the program don't show up in the file, but you've not used those.

Comment: Okay, but for example: the first med to be inserted, Hydrocontin, gets recorded right? If I exit the program and then run it again, through ./mm7, and I insert a new med, it allows to insert it with the same key of Hydrocontin, but this should not happen right?

Comment: If you want to reuse the data from prior runs, you need to avoid zapping it when you open (create) the file.  You have: `fd = open(FILEPATH, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0600);`.  The `O_TRUNC` truncates the file to empty if it already exists.  Remove that from your code and you should find yourself unable to re-enter key 1.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you one more time but something isn't working correctly :/ The data seems to be saved in the file but I can save two meds with the same key. The condition doens't seem to be working correctly when a shut down the application and run it again.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly. I would up-vote your answer but I don't have 15+ points of reputation :/ Post closed though.