# C creating a file with given size

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am trying to create a file with a given size using lseek() and adding a byte at the end of the file, however it creates a sparse file with 0 byte.

Below is the code...any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifndef BUF_SIZE
#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#endif // BUF_SIZE

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int inputFd;
    int fileSize = 500000000;
    int openFlags;
    int result;

    mode_t filePerms;
    ssize_t numRead;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    openFlags = O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL;
    filePerms = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH; /*rw-rw-ew*/

    inputFd = open(argv[1], openFlags, filePerms);
    if (inputFd == -1)
        printf("problem opening file %s ", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    printf ("input FD: %d", inputFd);


    result = lseek(inputFd, fileSize-1, SEEK_SET);
    if (result == -1){
        close(inputFd);
        printf("Error calling lseek() to stretch the file");
        return 1;
    }

    result = write(inputFd, "", 1);
    if (result < 0){
        close(inputFd);
        printf("Error writing a byte at the end of file\n");
        return 1;

    }

    if (close(inputFd) == -1)
        printf("problem closing file %s \n",argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want the file to grow and don't want the file to be sparse, you are pretty much reduced to seeking to the current end of file and writing the extra data needed in each block.  The [`ftruncate()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftruncate.html) can change the size of a file — shrink or grow it — but the specification makes no promises that the extra space will be 'real' (it could perfectly well be sparse).

Comment: the code already does that using lseek() and works fine

Comment: Agreed — once the problems diagnosed by Greg Hewgill are fixed.  The `ftruncate()` and `truncate()` functions can make the resizing process easier if sparseness doesn't matter.  If sparseness matters, as I said before, you actually have to write at least one byte in every block of the file that doesn't already exist.  'Tis a pain, but 'tis also the way the (Unix/POSIX) world works.

Comment: thanks Jeff :) will try ftruncate() ..

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you have any example of writing a byte on every block of the file...

Answer (score 5):

You are missing some braces:

```
if (inputFd == -1)
    printf("problem opening file %s ", argv[1]);
    return 1;
```

You need to change this to:

```
if (inputFd == -1) {
    printf("problem opening file %s ", argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
```

Without the braces, the only statement controlled by the `if` statement is the `printf`, and the `return 1;` statement is always run no matter what the value of `inputFd` is.

It is good practice to *always* use braces around a controlled block, even if there is only one statement (such as for the `close` at the end of your program).

Comment: It's also good practice to use a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: Another good practice is to enable `-Wall` which in-turn enables `-Wmisleading-indentation`, and the compiler will warn you of misleading indentation.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have any example of writing a byte on every block of the file?

This code is from a slightly different context, but can be adapted to your case.  The context was ensuring that the disk space for an Informix database was all allocated, so the wrapper code around this created the file (and it had not to exist, etc).  However, the entry point to actually writing was the second of these two functions — the fill buffer function replicated the 8-byte word `informix` into a 64 KiB block.

```
/* Fill the given buffer with the string 'informix' repeatedly */
static void fill_buffer(char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    size_t filled = sizeof("informix") - 1;

    assert(buflen > filled);
    memmove(buffer, "informix", sizeof("informix")-1);
    while (filled < buflen)
    {
        size_t ncopy = (filled > buflen - filled) ? buflen - filled : filled;
        memmove(&buffer[filled], buffer, ncopy);
        filled *= 2;
    }
}

/* Ensure the file is of the required size by writing to it */
static void write_file(int fd, size_t req_size)
{
    char buffer[64*1024];
    size_t nbytes = (req_size > sizeof(buffer)) ? sizeof(buffer) : req_size;
    size_t filesize = 0;

    fill_buffer(buffer, nbytes);

    while (filesize < req_size)
    {
        size_t to_write = nbytes;
        ssize_t written;
        if (to_write > req_size - filesize)
            to_write = req_size - filesize;
        if ((written = write(fd, buffer, to_write)) != (ssize_t)to_write)
            err_syserr("short write (%d vs %u requested)\n",
                        (int)written, (unsigned)to_write);
        filesize += to_write;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it writes in 64 KiB chunks.  Frankly, there's going to be no difference between writing all bytes on a page and writing one byte per page.  Indeed, if anything, writing the whole page will be faster because the new value can simply be written, whereas if you write just one byte per page, an old page has to be created/read, modified, and then written back.

In your context, I would extend the current file to a multiple of 4 KiB (8 KiB if you prefer), then go writing the main data blocks, and the final partial block if necessary.  You would probably simply do `memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));` whereas the sample code was deliberately writing something other than blocks of zero bytes.  AFAIK, even if the block you write is all zero bytes, the driver actually writes that block to the disk — the simple act of writing ensures the file is non-sparse.

The `err_syserr()` function is a bit like `fprintf(stderr, …)`, but it adds the system error message from `errno` and `strerror()` and exits the program too.  The code does assume 32-bit (or larger) `int` values.  I never got to experiment with terabyte size files — the code was last updated in 2009.

Comment: thanks Jeff, I am going to research on this, will let you know ho I get on