# Remove struct from mmaped array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, mmap

**Problem**: I have a struct called "med" to keep information about meds (Key, Name, MinimalQuantity and Quantity), with each med having a unique key. I stored an array of these structs in a memory mapped file, using mmap. Now I want to remove a specific med (struct) from the array, but it is not working...

**Code** :

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_MEDS 1000 
#define FILESIZE (NUM_MEDS * sizeof(struct med))

struct med
{
   int key;
   char name[25];
   int quant_min;
   int quant;
};

int main(void)
{
    int fd;
    int result;
    struct med *map;  /* mmapped array of structs */

    fd = open("meds.dat", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, (mode_t)0600);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Error opening file for writing");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = ftruncate(fd, FILESIZE); 
    if (result == -1)
    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error calling lseek() to 'stretch' the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Now the file is ready to be mmapped.  */
    map = (struct med *)mmap(0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error mmapping the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct med m;

    printf("Please enter the code of med: ");
    scanf("%d",&m.key);

    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < NUM_MEDS; j++)
    {
        if (m.key == map[j].key)
        {
            for(j; j < NUM_MEDS - 1; j++)
            {
            map[j] = map[j+1];
            }
            printf("Med %d removed with success\n",m.key);
            break;
        }
     }

     if (munmap(map, FILESIZE) == -1)
     {
         perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
     }

      close(fd);
      return 0;
}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: What's the error? Only `not working` is not helpful for others to help. Also, file size never changes, so you still have `1000` items in that file.

Comment: The end item of the array is a replicate of its former one, so it is subject to remove.

Comment: This is a continuation of [mmap and struct in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27697228).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual changes in functionality?  There were a couple.  First, you must nullify the last entry in the data after you've copied it down the list.  Second, you must recompute the number of entries after you've deleted some.

At the moment, you don't have a good way other than EOF of stopping inputs.  That meant I added data with one run of the program; I then had to run the program a second time to delete some data.  However, it seems to work correctly.  I added keys 1, 2, 3, 4 and then removed 2, 4 and the list left was 1, 3, which seems about right to me.

<sup>*I was asked about this by email as a result of answering the related question [mmap and struct in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27697228).*</sup>

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 800
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FILEPATH "/tmp/mmapped.bin"
#define NUM_MEDS 1000
#define FILESIZE (NUM_MEDS * sizeof(struct med))

struct med
{
    int key;
    char name[25];
    int quant_min;
    int quant;
};

static int find_num_entries(struct med *map, int max_meds);
static int get_new_key(struct med *map, int num_meds, int *key);
static int med_in_map(struct med *map, int num_meds, int key);
static int remove_key_med(struct med *map, int num_meds, int *key);
static int remove_med(struct med *map, int num_meds, int key);
static void insert_med_mmap(void);
static void interface(void);
static void list_meds_mmap(void);
static void load_meds_mmap(void);
static void print_med(char *tag, const struct med *med);
static void remove_med_mmap(void);
static void search_med_mmap(void);

int main(void)
{
    interface();
    return 0;
}

// interface
void interface(void)
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("=> Management and administration of Meds \n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("=> Mmap version \n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Choose your operation \n");
    printf("1- Insert med \n");
    printf("2- Remove med \n");
    printf("3- Search med \n");
    printf("4- List meds ordered by name \n");
    printf("5- Load meds \n");
    printf("6- Exit \n");

    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("\n");
        printf("Insert med \n");
        insert_med_mmap();
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("\n");
        printf("Remove med \n");
        remove_med_mmap();
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("\n");
        printf("Search med \n");
        search_med_mmap();
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("\n");
        printf("List meds ordered by name \n");
        list_meds_mmap();
        break;
    case 5:
        printf("\n");
        load_meds_mmap();
        break;
    case 6:
        return;
    }
}

static void print_med(char *tag, const struct med *med)
{
    printf("%s: %4d: Q(%2d, min %2d): %s\n",
           tag, med->key, med->quant, med->quant_min, med->name);
}

static int med_in_map(struct med *map, int num_meds, int key)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_meds; i++)
    {
        if (key == map[i].key)
        {
            printf("The med with key %d already exists in the file. \n", key);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

static int get_new_key(struct med *map, int num_meds, int *key)
{
    while (printf("Type the key of med: ") > 0 && scanf("%d", key) == 1)
    {
        if (med_in_map(map, num_meds, *key) == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return EOF;
}

static int find_num_entries(struct med *map, int max_meds)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < max_meds; i++)
    {
        if (map[i].key == 0)
            break;
    }
    return i;
}

static int remove_med(struct med *map, int num_meds, int key)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_meds; i++)
    {
        if (key == map[i].key)
        {
            for ( ; i < num_meds - 1; i++)
            {
                map[i] = map[i + 1];
            }
            printf("Med %d removed with sucess\n", key);
            map[i].key = 0;
            map[i].name[0] = '\0';
            map[i].quant = 0;
            map[i].quant_min = 0;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

static int remove_key_med(struct med *map, int num_meds, int *key)
{
    while (printf("Type the key of med: ") > 0 && scanf("%d", key) == 1)
    {
        if (remove_med(map, num_meds, *key) == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return EOF;
}

// load meds
void load_meds_mmap(void)
{
    printf("Test \n");
}

// insert med with mmap
void insert_med_mmap(void)
{
    int fd;
    int result;
    struct med *map;  /* mmapped array of structs */

    fd = open(FILEPATH, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, (mode_t)0600);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Error opening file for writing");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = ftruncate(fd, FILESIZE);
    if (result == -1)
    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error calling lseek() to 'stretch' the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    map = (struct med *)mmap(0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error mmapping the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Input loop */
    int num_meds;
    for (num_meds = find_num_entries(map, NUM_MEDS); num_meds < NUM_MEDS; num_meds++)
    {
        struct med m;
        memset(&m, '\0', sizeof(m));

        if (get_new_key(map, num_meds, &m.key) == EOF)
            break;

        printf("Name of med: ");
        if (scanf("%s", m.name) != 1)
            break;
        printf("Quant. min. of med: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &m.quant_min) != 1)
            break;
        printf("Quant. of med: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &m.quant) != 1)
            break;

        map[num_meds] = m;

        printf("Med %d saved.\n", m.key);
    }

    /* Output loop */
    printf("\nRecorded meds:\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_meds; i++)
    {
        char buffer[32];
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "M%.4d", i);
        print_med(buffer, &map[i]);
    }

    /* Don't forget to free the mmapped memory */
    if (munmap(map, FILESIZE) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
        /* Decide here whether to close(fd) and exit() or not. Depends... */
    }

    /* Un-mmapping doesn't close the file, so we still need to do that.  */
    close(fd);
}

// remove med with mmap
void remove_med_mmap(void)
{
    int fd;
    int result;
    struct med *map;  /* mmapped array of structs */

    fd = open(FILEPATH, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, (mode_t)0600);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Error opening file for writing");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = ftruncate(fd, FILESIZE);
    if (result == -1)
    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error calling lseek() to 'stretch' the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Now the file is ready to be mmapped.  */
    map = (struct med *)mmap(0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error mmapping the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Input loop */
    int num_meds;
    for (num_meds = find_num_entries(map, NUM_MEDS); num_meds < NUM_MEDS; num_meds++)
    {
        struct med m;
        memset(&m, '\0', sizeof(m));

        if (remove_key_med(map, num_meds, &m.key) == EOF)
            break;
    }

    /* Partial bug fix */
    num_meds = find_num_entries(map, NUM_MEDS);


    /* Output loop */
    printf("\nRecorded meds:\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_meds; i++)
    {
        char buffer[32];
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "M%.4d", i);
        print_med(buffer, &map[i]);
    }

    /* Don't forget to free the mmapped memory */
    if (munmap(map, FILESIZE) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
        /* Decide here whether to close(fd) and exit() or not. Depends... */
    }

    /* Un-mmapping doesn't close the file, so we still need to do that.  */
    close(fd);
    return;
}

void search_med_mmap(void)
{
    printf("Test \n");
}

void list_meds_mmap(void)
{
    printf("Test \n");
}
```